# Overflow error encountered in double scalars

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

Hi I am trying to do linear regression and this what happens to me when n I try to run the code
the code is :

```
    import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
df = data.dropna()
X = np.array(df.x)
Y = np.array(df.y)
def compute_error(x,y,m,b):
    error = 0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        error+= (y[i]-(m*x[i]+b))**2
    return error / float(len(x))

def step_graident_descent(x,y,m,b , alpha):
    N = float(len(x))
    b_graident = 0
    m_graident = 0
    for i in range(0 , len(x)):
        x = X[i]
        y = Y[i]
        b_graident +=(-2/N) * (y-(m*x+b))
        m_graident += (-2/N) * x*(y-(m*x+b))
    new_m = m - alpha*m_graident
    new_b = b - alpha*b_graident

    return new_m , new_b
def graident_decsent(x,y,m,b,num_itters,alpha):
    for i in range(num_itters):
        m,b = step_graident_descent(x,y,m,b,alpha)
    return m,b
def run():
    b=0
    m=0
    numberOfIttertions = 1000
    m,b = graident_decsent(X , Y ,m,b,numberOfIttertions , 0.001)
    print(m,b)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

and the error that i get is :

```
    linearRegression.py:22: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  m_graident += (-2/N) * x*(y-(m*x+b))
linearRegression.py:21: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  b_graident +=(-2/N) * (y-(m*x+b))
linearRegression.py:22: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  m_graident += (-2/N) * x*(y-(m*x+b))
```

if any one can help me i would be so greatfull since i am stuck on this for about two months and thankyou

Comment: Can you please add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Sure but i think it is minimal enough thanks

Comment: Well, it can't be reproducible as you did not provide the input data.

Comment: so how do you want me to add the data it is ariund 700 input and it is a csv so how do you want me to provide it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit: tl;dr Solution

Ok so here is the minimal reproducible example that I was talking of. I replace your X,Y by the following.

```
n = 10**2
X = np.linspace(0,10**6,n)
Y = 1.5*X+0.2*10**6*np.random.normal(size=n)
```

If I then run

```
b=0
m=0
numberOfIttertions = 1000
m,b = graident_decsent(X , Y ,m,b,numberOfIttertions , 0.001)
```

I get exactly the problem you describe. The only surprising thing is the ease of the solution. I just replace your alpha by 10**-14 and everything works fine.

#### Why and how to give a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Your example is not reproducible since we don't have `train.csv`. Generally both for understanding your problem yourself and to get concrete answers it is *very* helpful to have a very small example that people can run and tinker with it. E.g. maybe you can think of a much shorter input to your regression that also results in this error.

#### The first RuntimeWarning

But now to your question. Your first `RuntimeWarning` i.e.

```
    linearRegression.py:22: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  m_graident += (-2/N) * x*(y-(m*x+b))
```

means `x` and hence `m_graident` are of type `numpy.double=numpy.float64`. This datatype can store numbers in the range `(-1.79769313486e+308, 1.79769313486e+308).` If you go bigger or smaller that's called an overflow. E.g.
`np.double(1.79769313486e+308)`
is still ok but if you multiply it by say `1.1` you get your favorite runtime warning. Notice that this is 'just' a warning and still runs. But it can't give you a number back since it would be too big. instead it gives you `inf`.

#### The other RuntimeWarnings

Ok but what does

```
linearRegression.py:21: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  b_graident +=(-2/N) * (y-(m*x+b))
```

mean?

It comes from calculating with the infinity that I just mentioned. Some calculations with infinity are valid.

```
np.inf-10**6 -> inf
np.inf+10**6 -> inf
np.inf/10**6 -> inf
np.inf*10**6 -> inf
np.inf*(-10**6) -> -inf
1/np.inf -> 0
np.inf *np.inf -> inf
```

but some are not and give `nan` i.e. not a number.

```
np.inf/np.inf 
np.inf-np.inf
```

These are called indeterminate forms in math since it depends on how you got to the infinity what you would get out. E.g.

```
(np.double(1e+309)+np.double(1e+309))-np.double(1e+309)
np.double(1e+309)-(np.double(1e+309)+np.double(1e+309))
```

are both `inf-inf` but you would expect different results.
Getting a `nan` is unfortunate since calculations with `nan` yield always `nan`. And you can't use your gradients anymore once you add a `nan`.

#### Other resources

An other option is to use an existing implementation of linear regression. E.g. from `scikit-learn`. See

- [scikit-learn linear regression reference](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression)
- [scikit-learn user guid on linear models](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#ordinary-least-squares)

Comment: Thank you very much i see you spending the time and effort on this thankyou!

Comment: @majduddinalboon Solved it. Check out my answer again.